# Div placement in IE doesn't align right because of CSS Positioning

Tags: css, position, positioning, css-position

I have a fixed div that works perfect in Chrome and FF but for some reason in IE the fixed header gets pushed over to the right.

Looking at my CSS it seems to be the `position: relative;` on my "content" div because when I remove it, it works but them obviously my "content" is out of place then.

What would be the way of getting around this?

Here's a fiddle of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/ELUGc/1493/

Comment: Which version(s) of IE are you seeing this on?

Comment: Looking at this in ie10 and works perfectly for me

Comment: I am using IE 10 also so that's weird - Just checked and it works on jsfiddle fine but not just straight into IE10

Comment: I checked your fiddle in IE10 and used the developers tool bar and adjusted the Browser/Document mode.  Things seem to work fine until IE7, in which a large white space appears to the left of the header.  Is this worth fixing?

Comment: You must provide enough code to reproduce the problem, otherwise there's nothing to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IE is not in IE10 mode. Check with Developer Tools (press F12).

You can force the latest rendering mode by adding this inside `head`:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

This is irrelevant for you, since I'm near-certain you can fix the problem in the way I've already described, but if you wanted to fix IE7 (your IE10 is in IE7 mode) you could do it by adding `left: 0` to `#wrapper`.